# Equivalent of "for X in [list]" or "foreach"

Tags: python

In Python, we can evaluate an expression over specific values of *x* in a *list*.

Example:

```python
a = [4,5,6] # this is a list
x = range(len(a)) # this is pointer
for i in x:
    print a[i] # should print a[] elements
```

Many other languages call this operation [`foreach`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) instead of `for`.

Is there a way to accomplish the same in Mathematica?

Comment: You've seen `Map[]` and `Table[]`, no? Additionally, a lot of built-in functions are `Listable`, so that level of indirection isn't even needed.

Comment: The equivalent in Mathematica uses `Do`: `a = {1, 2, 3}; Do[Print[i], {i, a}]`. Python list comprehensions can be translated using `Table`. As @J.M. says, using `Map` and listability, this type of loop is often not necessary in Mathematica.

Comment: In fact, even in @Simon's example, you don't need a loop variable if you use `Scan[]`: `Scan[Print, a]`.

Comment: @J.M. No I am familar with loop constructs like Do[] to achieve that. Not Map[] or Table[]. I am trying to retrieve array elements via mapping for example in Python:

a = [4,5,6]
x = range(len(a))
for i in x:
    print a[i]

Comment: Right, so that was actually a nudge for you to look them up in the documentation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several constructs you can use. The one that comes closest to the [`foreach` of other languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) is

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
Do[Print[i], {i, a}]
```

Note that unlike in Python, the iterator variable `i` is local to `Do`.

There's an analogous [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) syntax. In Mathematica, we use `Table` much more frequently than `Do`.

[`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) and [`Scan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html) are also useful alternatives to [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html), for example `Scan[Print, a]`.

Further variants of these are discussed in [Applying Functions to Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html).

---

Finally, many functions in Mathematica have the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) [attribute](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html), which means that they automatically `Map` over lists:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable]

f[{1, 2, 3}]
(* {f[1], f[2], f[3]} *)
```

To be more precise, they automatically [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) over sets of lists:

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, {a, b, c}]
(* {f[1, a], f[2, b], f[3, c]} *)
```

Comment: This should fit OP's description too: `Function[i, Print[i]] /@ a`

Comment: @Kuba I did not want to complicate it by introducing a pure function just for the sake of showing an extra `i`. I do think it is an important and common question though, for people coming from other languages. That's why I added the `foreach` keyword to the title.

Comment: Great answer. May want to mention the fact that Mathematica tends towards local scoping in functions.  i.e. in your `Do` example the variable `i` is defined only within the loop.  In the Python construct `i` is global and retains the last value of the list after the `for` loop completes.  Something more akin to:  `Scan[(i=#;f[i])&,a];`