# Example of when explicitly using MapThread is better than giving a function the Listable Attribute

Tags: list-manipulation, attributes, mapthread

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155552/39270) says that `Listable` just makes the function automatically apply `MapThread` to its arguments.

Does anyone have a simple example of when explicitly using `MapThread` is better (or simply more convenient) then just giving a function the `Listable` attribute?

My guess is that if I have a function that works on lists (concatenating, etc), this would be such a case. Or perhaps theres an easy example using `Plot` (since a list of plot may not be desirable).

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit?

Comment: If it is a built in function, it's probably not a good idea to change its Listable status, else you might break something internally.

Answer (score 2):

Any function whose arguments are not "homogeneous" would be a candidate. Or any function whose arguments won't "align" properly during a threading. Or any function that expects some of its arguments to be lists with particular semantics in terms of size, position, etc. For example.

```
myF[a_String, {pre_String, post_String}] := pre <> a <> post
```

It works like this:

```
myF["hello", {"a", "b"}]
```

`"ahellob"`

But now,

```
SetAttributes[myF, Listable];
myF["hello", {"a", "b"}]
```

`{myF["hello", "a"], myF["hello", "b"]}`

We might want it to be Listable just on the first argument, so we could do this:

```
myF[{"hello", "goodbye"}, {"a", "b"}]
```

but that doesn't do what we want now:
`{myF["hello", "a"], myF["goodbye", "b"]}`

If we want to MapThread, we could have done it explicitly:

```
ClearAttributes[myF, Listable];
MapThread[myF, {{"hello", "goodbye"}, {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}}]
```

`{"ahellob", "cgoodbyed"}`

Or, if we want to thread just on the first argument, we can provide that definition:

```
myF[as : {___String}, pad : {_String, _String}] := 
  Activate[Thread[Inactive[myF][as, pad], List, 1]];
myF[{"hello", "goodbye"}, {"a", "b"}]
```

`{"ahellob", "agoodbyeb"}`